How to create a task that will be launched when any user logs in Windows
I have the following xml file which defines the settings for a windows task.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2023-06-12T17:19:37.124353</Date>
    <Author>DESKTOP-SREO20E\User</Author>
    <URI>\IngressServerConsole_Running_With_Windows</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
        <Duration>P3D</Duration>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-3687525730-1737640054-4077846089-1000</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>Queue</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT0S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>1</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>

When you log in as the user who created the task (with the same SID), the task works fine. But if I log in as a different user, or switch from one account to another, then my task does not work. What needs to be changed or specified to make the task work for all users?
